# Can I use the texts in my paper for bioconductor?

Tags: publications, plagiarism, self-plagiarism

My group has published a paper to a journal (Natural Methods). Now, I'd like to dump the text in the paper for my R-package vignette and user-manual (bioconductor).

Can I do it without reference our group's own paper? Or do I have to reference the journal? Does the journal hold the copyright for the published materials?

Comment: I think it is a pretty bad idea. The content I expect to find in an user manual is pretty different from that of a paper. Furthermore, having a reference to a published work greatly increases my confidence on the code.

Comment: Well, I'll add some contents, but I just want to copy-and-paste the sections about the project onto the user-manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The customary way to do this is to refer in the manual to the paper.

You are probably not allowed to copy-paste the text of the published paper. If you are concerned about the paywall, many journals allow you to use/distribute the manuscript which you submitted to the journal (prior to editing) - but you should verify this first for Nature Methods.